# Return data ordered by date

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel, laravel-5

I have a function that returns the count of sales each day. The problem with this approach is that I want the data to be stored by date but I am getting them in the following order:

```
01-Dec
02-Dec
03-Dec
03-Nov
04-Nov
05-Nov
etc.
```

I understand why that happens but I am not sure how to solve it. I can replace subMonth(1) with startofmonth which woul partially solve my problem but this is not what I want. I instead want to return the last 30 days ordered.

```
    return DB::table('sales')
        ->select(\DB::RAW('DATE_FORMAT(created_at, "%d-%M") as date'), \DB::raw('COUNT(*) as count'))
        ->where('created_at', '>=', Carbon::now()->subMonth(1))
        ->orderBy('date')
        ->groupBy('date')
        ->get(['date', 'count'])
        ->keyBy('date')
        ->transform(function ($data) {
            return $data->count;
        });
```

I also tried orderBy('created_at') but it gives me the error below and I'd like to avoid changing the sql mode.

```
Syntax error or access violation: 1055 Expression #3 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'x.sales.created_at' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by
```

**EDIT:**
As requested, this the sql query of the return statement

```
select DATE_FORMAT(created_at, "%d-%M") as date, COUNT(*) as count from `sales` where `created_at` >= ? group by `date` order by `date` asc
```

Comment: Please post generated SQL

Comment: @lad2025 I just did :)

Comment: Please try: `->groupBy('1')` instead of `->groupBy('date')`

Comment: why do you need groupBy ?

Comment: @George Did my suggestion help?

Comment: I just for testing, you use only created_at instead of  'DATE_FORMAT(created_at, "%d-%M") as date and do group by created_at and count (created_at) you still get the same error?

Comment: @lad2025 No I am getting an error: Unknown column '1' in 'group statement

Comment: @Radu I cannot use just created_at because the field is a timestamp, meaning it has date hour minute seconds so I cannot group by that because every row will be different

Comment: Ok I understand, what if you make this in 2 steps:


$s1 = DB::table('sales')
        ->select(\DB::RAW('DATE_FORMAT(created_at, "%d-%M") as date')))
        ->where('created_at', '>=', Carbon::now()->subMonth(1))
        ->orderBy('date')
        ->get(['date', 'count'])
       and after that
$s2 = $s1->select('date'), \DB::raw('COUNT(*) as count'))
        ->orderBy('date')
        ->groupBy('date')
        ->get(['date', 'count'])
        ->keyBy('date')

Comment: Did you solve it?

Answer (score 0):

i don't have much idea about your framework query syntax. but you can take one more column DATE_FORMAT(created_at, "%Y%m%d") AS order_column and apply order, and group by on column "order_column" and use column "data" while display data.

```
select DATE_FORMAT(created_at, "%Y%m%d") AS order_column, DATE_FORMAT(created_at, "%d-%M") as date, COUNT(*) as count from `sales` where `created_at` >= ? group by `order_column` order by `order_column` asc



return DB::table('sales')
        ->select(\DB::RAW('DATE_FORMAT(created_at, "%Y%m%d") AS order_column'),\DB::RAW('DATE_FORMAT(created_at, "%d-%M") as date'), \DB::raw('COUNT(*) as count'))
        ->where('created_at', '>=', Carbon::now()->subMonth(1))
        ->orderBy('order_column')
        ->groupBy('order_column')
        ->get(['date', 'count'])
        ->keyBy('date')
        ->transform(function ($data) {
            return $data->count;
        });
```

Comment: Yeap, that's the same as getting the raw 'created_at' values. I could just sort by the raw created_at but I am getting the error I mentioned above (sql_mode=only_full_group_by) with both cases. I suppose I will have to change the mysql setting to be done with this...

Answer (score 0):

If you make this in 2 steps does it work?

Step1 in which you create date column:

```
$step1 = DB::table('sales') ->select(\DB::RAW('DATE_FORMAT(created_at, "%d-%M") as date'))) 
->where('created_at', '>=', Carbon::now()->subMonth(1)) 
->orderBy('date') 
->get(['date', 'count'])
```

and after that you make the agregation:

```
$step2 = $step1->select('date'), \DB::raw('COUNT(date) as count')) 
->groupBy('date') ->get(['date', 'count']) ->keyBy('date')
```

Hope it helps!